# Prove the given determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove the given determinant:
$$\left|
\begin{matrix}
a&b&ax+by \\
b&c&bx+cy \\
ax+by&bx+cy&0 \\
\end{matrix}\right|=(b^2-ac)(ax^2+2bxy+cy^2)$$

I didn't get any idea. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Use the rule of Sarrus!

Comment: Similar problem here: https://www.topperlearning.com/doubts-solutions/using-the-property-of-determinants-prove-that-a-b-ax-by-b-c-bx-cy-b2-ac-ax2-2bxy-cy2-ax-by-bx-cy-0-fk7wteww/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

Set $$C_3'=C_3-xC_1-yC_2$$  to find

$$\left|
\begin{matrix}
a&b&0 \\
b&c&0 \\
ax+by&bx+cy&-x(ax+by)-y(bx+cy) \\
\end{matrix}\right|=?$$

Comment: I didn't get what does ${C_{3}}'=x.C_1+y.C_2$ mean?

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., $C_r$ means $r$th column, $C_t'$ modified $t$th column

Comment: How did you modify that? I mean using which property ?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... You can add or subtract multiples of rows or columns to a matrix without changing the determinant of the matrix. This is what is happening here. Essentially, we subtract $x$ times the first column and $y$ times the second column, from the third column.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, Thanks, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2):

Develop the determinant along the last line. You get

$$D_{a,b,c}(x,y)=(ax+by)\begin{vmatrix}b&ax+by\\c&bx+cy\end{vmatrix}-(bx+cy)\begin{vmatrix}a&ax+by\\b&bx+cy\end{vmatrix}$$

Now compute the $2\times 2$ déterminants to get

$$D_{a,b,c}(x,y)=(ax+by)\left(b(bx+cy)-c(ax+by)\right)-(bx+cy)\left(a(bx+cy)-b(ax+by)\right)$$

It simplifies quite well into

$$\begin{align}D_{a,b,c}(x,y)
=&(ax+by(b^2-ac)x+(bx+cy)(b^2-ac)y\\
=&(b^2-ac)(ax^2+2bxy+cy^2)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the day, here is the symmetric matrix version of this, writing $P^TAP = B,$ where $B$ is also symmetric with obvious determinant. We say that $A$ and $B$ are "congruent"

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
-x&-y&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&ax+by \\
b&c&bx+cy \\
ax+by&bx+cy&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&-x \\
0&1&-y \\
0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&0 \\
b&c&0 \\
0&0& - \left(a x^2 + 2bxy+cy^2 \right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$